# DIY Guitar Pedal, No Sound?

Tags: guitar

I've been building a guitar pedal for a school project. However, the one that I have built lets the sound of the guitar through when turned off but lets no sound through when turned on.

I did a pretty poor job of soldering, but I think the connections are viable. So aside from that, is there anything else that this could be indicative of?

(I can attach pictures if they are necessary.)

Thank you for any help you can provide, all of it is appreciated! :D

Answer (score 2):

> I did a pretty poor job of soldering, but I think the connections are
>   viable. So aside from that, is there anything else that this could be
>   indicative of?

Poor soldering = short circuits = not working. Diodes/transistors/chips soldered back to front = not working. Too much heat (due to poor soldering techniques) on certain components = broken components = not working. Not understanding wiring diagrams for switches = not working. Incorrect components fitted = usually not working. Dead battery = not working.